# Ошибка при запросе версии MySQL в терминале

Tags: mysql

ввожу в терминал `mysql -version` и мне выдает

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: И правильно делает. Правильная команда `mysql --version`

Comment: в любом случае когда я ввожу и другие команды

Comment: например, mysql -pМойПароль

Answer (score 1):

И правильно делает. Правильная команда `mysql --version`